# Why doesn't document.getElementById not work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

As the title suggest, somehow document.getElementById doesn't seem to retrieve the elements in the line:`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = saltgen(document.getElementById("num"));`

For context, I have unpacked the code into the Chrome extension.
Here is Code:

```js
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = saltgen(document.getElementById("num"));
}

function saltgen(length) {
  var salt = "";
  var symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var slength = symbols.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    salt = salt + symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * slength));
  }
  return salt;
}
```

```html
<html>
<br>
<h1>Set the number of characters</h1>
<input id="num" type="number" value="20"><br><br>
<button id="click">Generate</button>
<p id="text">Salt goes here</p>

<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="salt_genj.js"></script>

</html>
```

The error I used to have is "getElementById is not defined" at the line `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = saltgen(document.getElementById("num"));` " but after I have reloaded the error somehow doesn't show up, but when the button is clicked, the text "Salt goes here" simply disappears instead of being replaced with the result of the function defined in the javascript file.

Comment: You are passing the retrieved element to `saltgen()` instead of the value: `document.getElementById("num").value` will return the value of the input. Also you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` unless you specifically need the new value parsed as HTML.

Comment: @pilchard how would you pass the value into saltgen() istead of the element by itself?

Comment: As I noted above use `document.getElementById("num").value`

Comment: why doesn't not work, so it does work?

Comment: @pilchard Thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: @pilchard you can make your comment an answer so I can mark it as accepted for better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the retrieved element to `saltgen()` instead of the value.

You can retrieve the value from the element by accessing its [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#value) property: `document.getElementById("num").value` will return the value of the input.

Also, unless you specifically need the new value parsed as HTML, you should use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set the new text.

```js
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("text").textContent = saltgen(document.getElementById("num").value); // Access 'value' property
}

function saltgen(length) {
  var salt = "";
  var symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var slength = symbols.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    salt = salt + symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * slength));
  }
  return salt;
}
```

```html
<html>
<br>
<h1>Set the number of characters</h1>
<input id="num" type="number" value="20"><br><br>
<button id="click">Generate</button>
<p id="text">Salt goes here</p>

<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="salt_genj.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use debugging, or console output, to see whats wrong

```
function myFunction(){ 
    let num = document.getElementById("num");
    let salt = saltgen(num);
    console.info("num", num, "salt", salt)
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = salt;
 }
```

'num' is not the number but the element